# NSURLSessionTask, $_POST key => value pairs disappear over cellular?

Tags: php, objective-c, http-post, nsurlsession, cellular-network

In my iOS app, I have an `NSURLSessionTask` that works as it should over WiFi connections to the internet (and thus it must be formatted correctly). But when I connect over a cellular network my php on the server reports that no `$_POST key => value` pairs are found.

Is there some sort of security that I am not aware of truncating these, or something?

(It is not the `allowCellularAccess` property, as this is set to YES and the connection is made, minus the post pairs.)